# Toggling i18n fields in a JavaScript webapp in a scalable way

Tags: javascript, user-interface, scalable

I'm writing a 100% JavaScript webapp that manages a catalog of products. 
I'm using Backbone & Mustache, among other things.

Each product has a name, which needs to be translated. So for each product, I add as many `<input>` elements as there are languages to translate, something like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name_fr" value="Bonjour" class="i18n lang_fr">
<input type="text" name="name_en" value="Hello" class="i18n lang_en">
<input type="text" name="name_es" value="Hola" class="i18n lang_es">
```

I show/hide `<input>` elements depending on the currently selected language relying on CSS classes, on the first rendering and also when the user changes the language :

```
var $html = ...; // Render Mustache template

var cssClass = 'lang_' + currentLanguageId;

$html.find('.i18n.' + cssClass).show();
$html.find('.i18n:not(.' + cssClass + ')').hide();
```

This method is a maybe a little bit naïve, but it is simple, because each input field contains all the necessary information in its attributes to save the data. I'm listening the `blur` event to save data when the user leaves the field.

The problem is that the language switch is **slow** when the number of elements grows.

Am I using the good technique ? I don't think re-rendering the product items when the language changes would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use css instead of javascript to toggle the show/hide?

E.g.:

```
.lang_fr,.lang_en,.lang_es {display:none}
.fr .lang_fr {display:inline}
.en .lang_en {display:inline}
.es .lang_es {display:inline}

...

<div class="fr">
  <input type="text" name="name_fr" value="Bonjour" class="i18n lang_fr">
  <input type="text" name="name_en" value="Hello" class="i18n lang_en">
  <input type="text" name="name_es" value="Hola" class="i18n lang_es">
</div>
```

Then just toggle the `fr` class of the outer div.

Comment: Brilliant ! I just need to generate the CSS classes dynamically with my scripting language.